# Visual Studio Code with CMake Tools: launch.json not generated correctly?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake

I am trying to configure VSCode for debugging my code. My project is configured by CMake. I use the CMake Tools extensions. Configuring and building as well as quick debugging works so far.

But since I want to configure the launch specifications I let VSCode generate the launch.json file according to:
"Visual Studio Code generates a launch.json with almost all of the required information." https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/launch-json-reference

I do this by having my main.cpp tab open and then clicking on "create a launch.json file". (See picture.)
[image: VS Code Run and Debug]

I am working in a Ubuntu 18.04 environment. Which is why I select `C++ (GDB/LLDB)` from the command pop up.
[image]

Then a launch.json is created and opened. But it looks extremely empty. See here:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": []
}
```

I expected something more like the example from the VS json reference page:

```
{
    "name": "C++ Launch",
    "type": "cppdbg",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/a.out",
    "args": ["arg1", "arg2"],
    "environment": [{ "name": "config", "value": "Debug" }],
    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
}
```

Am I missing something? Since I have only a very brief idea of my possibilities with the launch.json and what is required to fill in to make it work correctly, I hoped that VS Code would help me out here.

Comment: Yes it should add more data, did you try clicking add again? Note that the cmake plugin has no effect on launch.json generation

Comment: Yes, I did. Multiple times. I also tried deleting the generated launch.json and letting it generate again.

Comment: They're not that difficult to write by hand, see the camke plugin documentation for an example

Comment: CMake Tools documentation explains how to write a `launch.json` wired up to the selected target: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/blob/main/docs/debug-launch.md#debug-using-a-launchjson-file

Comment: @SpacePotatoes Thank you. For now there really seems to be no other solution than to write it by hand.